# Select values from dataframe in spark

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I want to select particular values using loop.
I have a data frame named `df` with a lot of columns, and I want to select the values which is less than 1 and NULL. Is there any efficient way to get the values?

```
//select values from column 1  
val a = df.filter(df("1") < 1||df("1").isNull)
```

Comment: you could use `when/otherwise` function on columns if you want to select columns based on value.. is this what you are expecting? or you need to select only columns in which the value is less than 1 or null?

Answer (score 0):

is there any way to add loop in following code for process several columns 
 val a = df.filter(df("1") < 1||df("1").isNull)